# Add new record button in RadGrid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I follow [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/templateformupdate/defaultcs.aspx) on how to create grid with my custom New Item control. I have quite easy question - where do I define New record button, just like this one in demo?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the RadGrid's attribute **AllowAutomaticInserts** is set to True, and the grid is using a [declarative data source](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-automatic-datasource-operations.html), you'll get the default "Add New" button and behavior. This is what's happening in the demo you linked. You can control its appearance in several ways.

The "command items" (add, delete, edit, etc.) associated with the grid are controlled by  the grid's **CommandItemTemplate** element.  By default the look of this element will be based on the skin you have applied to the Telerik controls.  It can also be controlled with various [style elements](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commanditem-default-behavior.html).)

The CommandItemTemplate can be customized to show custom buttons, nonstandard text, and so forth.  Here's an example from [Telerik's documentation on it](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commanditemtemplate.html).  Note that the CommandName attribute determines what function is performed by the button.

```
<CommandItemTemplate>
Custom command item template
<asp:LinkButton Style="vertical-align: bottom" ID="btnEditSelected" runat="server"
    CommandName="EditSelected" Visible='<%# RadGrid1.EditIndexes.Count == 0 %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/Edit.gif" /> Edit Selected Customers</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateEdited" runat="server" CommandName="UpdateEdited" Visible='<%# RadGrid1.EditIndexes.Count > 0 %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/Update.gif" /> Update Customers</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="CancelAll" Visible='<%# RadGrid1.EditIndexes.Count > 0 || RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/Cancel.gif" /> Cancel editing</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName="InitInsert" Visible='<%# !RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/AddRecord.gif" /> Add new Customer</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandName="PerformInsert" Visible='<%# RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/Insert.gif" /> Add this Customer</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Delete all selected customers?')"
    runat="server" CommandName="DeleteSelected"><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/Delete.gif" /> Delete Selected Customers</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CommandName="Re bindGrid"><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="../../DataEditing/Img/Refresh.gif" /> Refresh customer list</asp:LinkButton>
<br />
</CommandItemTemplate>
```

Also, the grid's MasterTableView contains an attribute, [CommandItemDisplay](http://www.telerik.com.ag/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-styling-the-gridcommanditem-visual.html), which can be used to control the button placement - values are None, Top, TopAndBottom, or Bottom:

```
<MasterTableView   CommandItemDisplay="Top"  ....>
```

Comment: The `CommandItemSettings` tag can also modify how the command items are displayed and act.